# gets() not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I have tried many things but with no result. I have used `<cstdio>` but no help.
Again I tried to use fget but did not get any good result. i used online compiler http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool check;
    char sntn[100],word[100],test[20];
    gets (word);
    gets (sntn);
    int j=0,count=0,val,k;
    check=true;
    while(check) {
        for(; sntn[j]==32; j++) {
            test[k]=sntn[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    k=0;
    j+=1;
    val=strcmp(test,word);
    if(val==0)
        count++;
    if(sntn[j]==32) {
        j+=1;
        check=true;
    }
    if(sntn[j]=='\0')
        check=false;

    cout<<endl<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:9:11: error: ‘gets’ was not declared in this scope
 gets (word);
           ^
```

Comment: I have omitted `stdio.h` and used a single `cstdio`, but still got the same error.

Comment: Tip: you can use free programs such as AStyle to format your code before posting it.

Comment: Just use `string` and `getline`, both in namespace `std` and from the `<string>` header.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, sorry i am new to Stackoverflow, so not aware of Astyle.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf please elaborate

Comment: Uhm, google it? I'm busy with breakfast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) has been deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++14. The online compiler must use C++14 or later version of the language.

More importantly, `gets` is known to be a security problem. Don't use it even if the compiler supports it. Use [`std::fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) instead.

Unless you are required to use functions from the `<cstdio>` header, there are better alternatives with `std::string`.

1. [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
2. [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

The links contain example code to get you started.

Comment: The question is tagged C++. Why not recommend `std::getline` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: How to use it? It will be of great help if you elaborate the usage of fgets.I tried that but in vain.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty, follow the links. They have example code to get you started.